# How to get the latest status from the table while using max(date)

Tags: sql, oracle

**Here is one table name called..
COMPLAINTS :-**

```
COMNO       CDATE           MESSAGE                             STATUS
----------------------------------------------------------------------
12345       05-JAN-22       CUSTOMER ISSUE REPORTED             OPEN        
12345       07-JAN-22       WAITING FOR THE CUSTOMER RESPONCE   IN PROGRESS
12345       09-JAN-22       ISSUE RESOLVED                      CLOSED
56789       14-JAN-22       CUSTOMER ISSUE REPORTED             OPEN
56789       23-JAN-22       ISSUE RESOLVED                      CLOSED
85642       03-JAN-22       CUSTOMER ISSUE REPORTED             OPEN
78632       30-JAN-22       CUSTOMER ISSUE REPORTED             OPEN
78632       31-JAN-22       WAITING FOR THE CUSTOMER RESPONCE   IN PROGRESS
```

Here is my oracle query -

```
SELECT COMNO,
       MIN(CDATE) AS COMPLAINT_CREATION_DATE,
       MAX(CDATE) AS COMPLAINT_CLOSURE_DATE
  FROM COMPLAINT 
 WHERE CDATE BETWEEN TO_DATE('01/Jan/2022 00:00:00','dd/Mon/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')     AND TO_DATE('31/Jan/2022 23:59:59','dd/Mon/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') 
   AND REFNO='12345'
 GROUP BY COMNO
```

which gives me the result of REFNO='12345'

```
COMNO       COMPLAINT_CREATION_DATE   COMPLAINT_CLOSURE_DATE
--------------------------------------------------------
12345       05-JAN-22                 09-JAN-22
```

In this query i want to add the last status and message of all complaints

```
COMNO + COMPLAINT_CREATION_DATE + COMPLAINT_CLOSURE_DATE + MESSAGE + STATUS
-------------------------------------------------------------------
12345       05-JAN-22       09-JAN-22       ISSUE RESOLVED                      CLOSED
56789       14-JAN-22       23-JAN-22       ISSUE RESOLVED                      CLOSED
85642       03-JAN-22       03-JAN-22       CUSTOMER ISSUE REPORTED             OPEN
78632       30-JAN-22       31-JAN-22       WAITING FOR THE CUSTOMER RESPONCE   IN PROGRESS
```

Can anyone please help me on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a self-join, use `KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY CDATE)`:

```sql
SELECT COMNO,
       MIN(CDATE) AS COMPLAINT_CREATION_DATE,
       MAX(CDATE) AS COMPLAINT_CLOSURE_DATE,
       MAX(MESSAGE) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY CDATE) AS message,
       MAX(STATUS)  KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY CDATE) AS status
  FROM COMPLAINT 
 WHERE CDATE >= DATE '2022-01-01'
   AND CDATE <  DATE '2022-02-01' 
   AND REFNO='12345'
 GROUP BY COMNO
```

Or analytic functions:

```sql
SELECT comno,
       COMPLAINT_CREATION_DATE,
       cdate AS COMPLAINT_CLOSURE_DATE,
       message,
       status
FROM   (
  SELECT c.*,
         MIN(CDATE) OVER (PARTITION BY comno) AS COMPLAINT_CREATION_DATE,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY comno ORDER BY cdate DESC) AS rn
    FROM COMPLAINT c
   WHERE CDATE >= DATE '2022-01-01'
     AND CDATE <  DATE '2022-02-01' 
     AND REFNO='12345'
)
WHERE  rn = 1
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE complaint (REFNO, COMNO, CDATE, MESSAGE, STATUS) AS
SELECT '12345', 12345, DATE '2022-01-05', 'CUSTOMER ISSUE REPORTED', 'OPEN' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '12345', 12345, DATE '2022-01-07', 'WAITING FOR THE CUSTOMER RESPONCE', 'IN PROGRESS' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '12345', 12345, DATE '2022-01-09', 'ISSUE RESOLVED', 'CLOSED' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '12345', 56789, DATE '2022-01-14', 'CUSTOMER ISSUE REPORTED', 'OPEN' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '12345', 56789, DATE '2022-01-23', 'ISSUE RESOLVED', 'CLOSED' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '12345', 85642, DATE '2022-01-03', 'CUSTOMER ISSUE REPORTED', 'OPEN' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '12345', 78632, DATE '2022-01-30', 'CUSTOMER ISSUE REPORTED', 'OPEN' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '12345', 78632, DATE '2022-01-31', 'WAITING FOR THE CUSTOMER RESPONCE', 'IN PROGRESS' FROM DUAL
```

Both output:

> | COMNO | COMPLAINT_CREATION_DATE | COMPLAINT_CLOSURE_DATE | MESSAGE | STATUS |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 12345 | 2022-01-05 00:00:00 | 2022-01-09 00:00:00 | ISSUE RESOLVED | CLOSED |
> | 56789 | 2022-01-14 00:00:00 | 2022-01-23 00:00:00 | ISSUE RESOLVED | CLOSED |
> | 78632 | 2022-01-30 00:00:00 | 2022-01-31 00:00:00 | WAITING FOR THE CUSTOMER RESPONCE | IN PROGRESS |
> | 85642 | 2022-01-03 00:00:00 | 2022-01-03 00:00:00 | CUSTOMER ISSUE REPORTED | OPEN |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=a54ab6985bdd3fe3e7f9d2836cb0418d)*

Comment: This is definitely a better solution than mine.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the filter condition form your query and join it again to the table -

```
SELECT C.COMNO,
       CD.COMPLAINT_CREATION_DATE,
       CD.COMPLAINT_CLOSURE_DATE,
       C.MESSAGE,
       C.STATUS
  FROM (SELECT COMNO,
               MIN(CDATE) AS COMPLAINT_CREATION_DATE,
               MAX(CDATE) AS COMPLAINT_CLOSURE_DATE
          FROM COMPLAINT 
         WHERE CDATE BETWEEN TO_DATE('01/Jan/2022 00:00:00','dd/Mon/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
                         AND TO_DATE('31/Jan/2022 23:59:59','dd/Mon/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') 
         GROUP BY COMNO) CD
  JOIN COMPLAINTS C ON CD.COMNO = C.COMNO
                   AND CD.COMPLAINT_CLOSURE_DATE = C.CDATE;
```

[Demo.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=a914a28edf22a23fcff6084ced41a30a)